# SQL Server Top (1) Less than not getting proper results

Tags: sql, sql-server

OK, using the following

```
SELECT TOP (1) PicsID from Pics WHERE (PicsID < 130)
```

this SHOULD give me the previous record in line, of which would be 129, However, it jumps to the beginning of the set, and gives me the first record in the table, of which is Record #1 not #129

I have a more complex Query in another site, that does this properly, and gives the next number in line, however, using it like this, does not work.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify an `order by`.  You gave only a limit.  SQL Server is permitted to return an arbitrary choice of matching rows.  You need:

```
SELECT TOP (1) PicsID from Pics WHERE (PicsID < 130)
ORDER BY PicsID desc
```

Comment: Dang, I should have refreshed the page :) I figured that out as well.... and posted it below as Answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

```
SELECT TOP (1) PicsID from Pics WHERE (PicsID < 130) order by picsid desc
```

Had to add the order by, in order to get the previous record.

Wayne